# Android service stopped, memory same as before

Tags: java, android, memory, service

When I stop one service of my application, the memory usage is the same as when the service runs. If I don't start this service it doesn't get increased.
Why Android doesn't release the memory of the service when it gets stopped by my main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garbage Collector may be run at a later time to remove objects there are no references to. It doesn't happen right after you release object.

Comment: this means there won't be an overconsumption of memory? or an Error because there is not enough memory?

Comment: No error will occur if code is otherwise correct. Garbage will be collected usually before next big thing is allocated (Activity or new instance of the Service).

Comment: ok I will test my service for some hours, by now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Android Doesn't allocate system memory for each object allocation and that include Context objects (Activity, Service ...).

Since each android app runs on its **DVM** android gives that VM a specific Memory, depending on the OS state, available memory and other factors.

The application will use that memory and if the **KVM** requested more memory the OS will try to allocate more for it, so on the linux Process Level you don't get to see Objects allocations effect. infact I doubt you can see that on any Modern VM.

And same goes for deallocation.

Take a look here : [JVM Memory](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp) it is not KVM but they share the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no more references to an object, GC will release it eventually. Error due to lack of memory should not appear, because GC will be run when memory gets low.

Make sure you release an object when the service is stopped.